# Pandas - accumulate values within certain time interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum, accumulator

Suppose I have

```
df

                          ts  v
0 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1
1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2
2 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3
3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4
```

I want to append a column s, such that in every row, it contains the sum of `v`s within a 1-second lookback time interval, such as

```
desired_df
   s                         ts  v
0  1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1
1  3 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2
2  3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3
3  7 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4
```

So, how do I generate this additional column `s`?

**Noe that the intervals should be overlapping, but they must have right endpoint at every row(datapoint) in the dataframe, i.e. every row(datapoint) in my dataframe must be a right endpoint of an interval of that size.**

EDIT: THE ANSWER BELOW IS NOT RIGHT?COMPLETE

EDIT: I would like the solution to work for a generic time interval, such as 14ms, not necessarily just for 1 second.

How about

```
df['s'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='400mS')).transform(numpy.cumsum)
```

I got

```
                          ts  v  s
0 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1  1
1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2  2
2 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3  3
3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4  7
```

Isn't the row indexed 1 wrong? s at 03:39:42.500914 should be 2+1=3. not 2, because the first 2 rows are within 400ms, so it should add them together. Why is it not doing that?

EDIT: When I try

```
df['s'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='340mS')).transform(numpy.cumsum)
```

It actually performs that grouping, even though the time interval is smaller:

```
                            v  s
ts                              
2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1  1
2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2  3
2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3  3
2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4  7
```

So, where are the delimiters(separators) that TimeGrouper places? I want the right endpoint of the interval to coincide with the row I am looking at(the row that s corresponds to)

Answer (score 3):

set `ts` as index and then `groupby` second, and transform with `cumsum()` as a new column **s**, then apply `reset_index`, like this:

```
df
                          ts  v
0 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1
1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2
2 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3
3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4

df = df.set_index('ts')

df['s'] = df.groupby(lambda x: x.second).transform(cumsum)
df = df.reset_index()
df

                          ts  v  s
0 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1  1
1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2  3
2 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3  3
3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4  7
```

You may want to reorder the columns:

```
df = df[['s','ts','v']]
df
   s                         ts  v
0  1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1
1  3 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2
2  3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3
3  7 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4
```

#### Updated

As OP updates that a generic method is need, `pd.TimeGrouper` can be used:

**Another updates (full steps provided)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914',1],['2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914', 2],['2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914',3],['2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914', 4]], columns=['ts','v'], dtype=object)

# you will get type error if you haven't converted your string to datetime 
df['ts'] = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in df['ts']]

df = df.set_index('ts')
```

#### See this line

```
# from the doc we need to add closed='left' to include the first nbin count
df['s'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='340mS', closed='left')).transform(cumsum)

# reset the index
df = df.reset_index()

# reorder the columns
df = df[['s', 'ts', 'v']]

df
   s                         ts  v
0  1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1
1  3 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2
2  3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3
3  7 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4
```

However on '400mS' I agreed we still not getting the desire result.

Comment: If you have one vent at 12:15:11.9 and another at 12:15:12.1, your solution won't group them together, because the second is different(11s vs 12s), but they should be together, because they happen inside one second. Please see my edit of the original question.

Comment: @BaronYugovich, you should have mentioned this in OP. No problem, I updated my answer as well

Comment: oh you mean the freq from the first record on or I got it misunderstood?

Comment: This looks better. Give me a few minutes to experiment with it, and come back and accept your answer, if it checks out.

Comment: I'm getting NameError: name 'cumsum' is not defined.
Please post the full sequence of commands you ran, another error I see is TypeError: axis must be a DatetimeIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Comment: @BaronYugovich, answer updated with full steps, you were getting the TypeError probably because you haven't converted the string to datetime, or you have the df['s'] column in your DataFrame already.

Comment: Can you please try df['s'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='400mS')).transform(numpy.cumsum) ?

I am getting 
 df
Out[48]: 
                          ts  v  s
0 2014-11-03 03:39:42.200914  1  1
1 2014-11-03 03:39:42.500914  2  2
2 2014-11-03 03:39:43.600914  3  3
3 2014-11-03 03:39:43.620914  4  7

Comment: Please look at my edits of the original question, this answer almost works, but some experiments/tests still fail.

Comment: @BaronYugovich, I checked, actually we need to add `closed='left'` so the first nbin is counted.

Comment: Here is my situation in more detail: the intervals should be overlapping, but they have to have right endpoint at every row(datapoint) in the dataframe. How do we achieve this? I think that TimeGrouper simply divides the time axis in uniform, non-overlapping intervals.

Comment: Please note my edits of the original question showed in bold.